# In clojure, is there a doseq-like function that receives a function instead of body

Tags: clojure, iteration

I want to repeatedly executes a function **for its side-effects** on a collection.
The common way is:

```
(defn my-func [x] (println x))
(doseq [x '(1 2 3) ]
       (my-func x))
```

But the **x** variable is a little bit cumbersome. I prefer the following code:

```
 ((comp doall map) my-func '(1 2 3))
```

Do you think this is an elegant solution?

Comment: [`run!`](https://clojure.github.io/clojure/clojure.core-api.html#clojure.core/run!) is the answer from the future: it was added to Clojure in release 1.7.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

[`clojure.core/dorun`](http://clojuredocs.org/clojure_core/clojure.core/dorun) is better than `doall`, because `doall` holds the whole sequence in memory in order to return it to you. `dorun` returns `nil`, just as `doseq` does. To say that the language core "should" offer something like `domap` is a bit aggressive - for a language that discourages mutation and side effects, Clojure already has plenty of functions that are very *close* to what you want and are easy to combine.

Answer (score 4):

I actually quite like:

```
((comp dorun map) my-func '(1 2 3))
```

It's a good example of "point free style" in Clojure. The higher order function `(comp dorun map)` is potentially useful elsewhere.... you might name it "apply-to-sequence" or something similar.

You could also use the following (amalloy's suggestion) which is also points-free and probably a bit more idiomatic:

```
(dorun (map my-func '(1 2 3)))
```

However be aware that both solutions using map will construct an intermediate (lazy) sequence to hold the result of the map function. This implies a small amount of extra overhead, so if you care about performance then I think the standard way using [doseq](http://clojuredocs.org/clojure_core/clojure.core/doseq) is better, i.e..

```
 (doseq [x '(1 2 3)] (my-func x))
```

Comment: This is no fewer points than `(dorun (map my-func '(1 2 3)))`, and the latter is surely more common. I guess I don't have a strong opinion about which is more readable, but this doesn't really exemplify point-free style.

Comment: Agree, `(dorun (map my-func '(1 2 3))` is also point-free example and perhaps a bit more idiomatic. Included both in the answer.

Answer (score 2):

Use `doseq`. Don't combine lazy sequences with side effects. It can lead to unexpected results, for example with chunked sequences.

Answer (score 0):

Why don't you just write a function that takes a function and a sequence and applies the function to the sequence via doseq.

e.g.

```
user=> (defn doseqf [fun seq] (doseq [x seq] (fun x)))
#'user/doseqf
user=> (doseqf println '(1 2 3))
1
2
3
nil
```

Comment: Indeed, it works but I want to refrain from writing functions that should be offered by the language core libraries.

Comment: If you think it should be in the core library, then you should open a bug report and offer the fix.

Comment: That's good advice in general, but this function isn't getting into clojure.core in a million years. Nobody wants to further pollute the core namespace for something as trivial as `(comp dorun map)`.

Comment: I agree 100% w/amalloy. So, looking at it, map applies the function to the sequence, and dorun forces the evaluation, correct? I could have used that a couple of weeks ago.

Answer (score 0):

I share your interest for map's laconic style, and I also dislike having to create temporary variables in such cases.

Luckily you can easily write that function yourself:

```
(defn domap
  "Implementation of Common Lisp `mapc`. It is like `map` except that the 
   results of applying function are not accumulated. The `colls` argument 
   is returned."
  [f & colls]
  (reduce (fn [_ args]
            (apply f args))
          nil (apply map list colls))
  colls)
```

Now you have a mapping function for side effects:

```
(domap println '(1 2 3))
```

Answer (score 0):

Most of the answers here were written before release 1.7, in which such a function was added to Clojure.

That function is [`run!`](https://clojure.github.io/clojure/clojure.core-api.html#clojure.core/run!).

`(run! f coll)` is equivalent to `(dorun (map f coll))`. Prefer `run!` in Clojure 1.7 and later.